# jQuery .click() and .on('click') not working

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to JavaScript an I have been trying to edit this [code on this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html) to work for me. So far I have successfully managed to get the correct form number at the top of each one, but I was not able to get the form numbers to fix after deleting the set of form fields. Here is the code so far:
HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove review" class="delete" /><br /><br />
<p class='sometext'>Some text </p>

<input name="cd" value="title" />

<select name="rankingsel">
    <option>Rating</option>
    <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
    <option value="good">Good</option>
    <option value="ok">OK</option>
    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    <option value="bad">Bad</option>
</select><br /><br />

<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
<br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:<br />
<input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2
```

JavaScript:

```
var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
    counter+=1;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    var n = $("[class^='sometext'").length;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i+=1) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName){
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
        }
        if (newField[i].className == 'sometext'){
            $(newField[i]).append(document.createTextNode(n));
        }
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#moreFields').click(function(){
        moreFields();
    });
    $('#readroot').on('click','.delete',function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        var countClass = 0;
        $('.sometext').each(function(){
            countClass += 1;
            this.innerHTML = "Some text " + countClass;
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is nothing happens when I click the Remove review button and I also tried doing $('.delete').click instead but that didn't work either. Here is the code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfht2ky8/1/).

Comment: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [class^='sometext'` on "Give me more fields" button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are calling `.on()` on must exist at the time of calling. In your case, the dynamically added `#readroot` clones don't exist at the time of calling `.on()`. Call `.on()` on something that exist at the time of binding, like say, `document`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dfht2ky8/2/

Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    ...
});
```